# LINQ converting string to int

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I have this linq query which is making a selection and then trying to sum the totals so under each group key there is a sum total. The value is a string and I cannot sum a string. however when i try to convert to int I get an error:

LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 ToInt32(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

```
 var dataSet = entities.BL_MT_CATEGORY
            .Distinct()
            .Where(d => (iGeography.FirstOrDefault() == "" || iGeography.Contains(d.Geography))
            && (iRetailer.FirstOrDefault() == "" || iRetailer.Contains(d.Retailer))
            && (iCountry.FirstOrDefault() == "" || iCountry.Contains(d.Country))
            && (iAirport.FirstOrDefault() == "" || iAirport.Contains(d.Airport))
            && (iShop.FirstOrDefault() == "" || iShop.Contains(d.StoreName))
            && (iCategory.Contains(d.Category))
            && (d.Values == "Sum of EuroValue"))
            .GroupBy(x => x.Category)
            .Select(g => new {
                C201408 = g.Sum(x => Convert.ToInt32(x.C201408))
            })
            .ToList();
```

Comment: @vendettamit There is no explicit cast between `string` and `int`.

Comment: use entity framework functions,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try moving the conversion outside of the query.

```
var dataSet = entities.BL_FERRERO_MT_CATEGORY
        .Distinct()
        .Where(d => (iGeography.FirstOrDefault() == "" || iGeography.Contains(d.Geography))
        && (iRetailer.FirstOrDefault() == "" || iRetailer.Contains(d.Retailer))
        && (iCountry.FirstOrDefault() == "" || iCountry.Contains(d.Country))
        && (iAirport.FirstOrDefault() == "" || iAirport.Contains(d.Airport))
        && (iShop.FirstOrDefault() == "" || iShop.Contains(d.StoreName))
        && (iCategory.Contains(d.Category))
        && (d.Values == "Sum of EuroValue"))
        .ToList()
        .GroupBy(x => x.Category)
        .Select(g => new {
            C201408 = g.Sum(x => Convert.ToInt32(x.C201408))});
```

This is make the LINQ to Entities convert the valid query. After that it will perform the grouping and selection of the `.Sum()`.

Comment: Works, but highly inefficient. Not that there is good L2E solution though. That's why number/dates should not be stored as strings.

Comment: You are correct that it is not as efficient. Just as you stated, it can't be extremely efficient when the data is stored incorrectly. Also, depending on the application, certain optimizations, such as this one, might not be that important.

Answer (score 0):

Fetch only the column that you want to sum and make tolist  than sum.

```
var dataSet = entities.BL_FERRERO_MT_CATEGORY
        .Distinct()
        .Where(d => (iGeography.FirstOrDefault() == "" || iGeography.Contains(d.Geography))
        && (iRetailer.FirstOrDefault() == "" || iRetailer.Contains(d.Retailer))
        && (iCountry.FirstOrDefault() == "" || iCountry.Contains(d.Country))
        && (iAirport.FirstOrDefault() == "" || iAirport.Contains(d.Airport))
        && (iShop.FirstOrDefault() == "" || iShop.Contains(d.StoreName))
        && (iCategory.Contains(d.Category))
        && (d.Values == "Sum of EuroValue"))
        .Select(x=>x.C201408)
        .ToList()
        .Sum(x=>int.Parse(x));
```